# redirect subdomain to ip, but in web browser, redirect to folder

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domains

I have a Minecraft server with the ip of mc.s0l4re.com, the mc subdomain is an "A" DNS record that redirects anyone typing "mc.s0l4re.com" in Minecraft to my server. However I want to use this subdomain as a website for my server as well. I want to redirect anyone in minecraft who types in "mc.s0l4re.com" to my Minecraft server, but I want anyone using a web browser to be directed to the server website.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your question?  What did you try?  How did it fail?

Answer (score 2):

The `A` record in DNS is an *address mapping record* that only resolves the name to an IP. DNS doesn't implement [HTTP redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4): it's a feature of HTTP protocol i.e. performed by a web server.

If you are running a [Minecraft server](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server) on its default port `25565` i.e. have `server-port=25565` in your [Server.properties](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties), you have the default port `80` for HTTP (and `443` for HTTPS) available.

You can set up a web server ([Apache](https://httpd.apache.org), [Nginx](https://nginx.org) etc.) on the same server, having the same hostname for

- serving your website.
- performing a [redirection](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) to another site.
- [reverse proxying](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) your external web site to that address.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify if the web server that will serve your site will be on the same machine as your minecraft server or on a different machine.

If on the same machine then you don't need redirect. Just setup a web server and put your website files there.

If website and minecraft server are on different machines then you must redirect to an other domain to display your website and the other domain must point to the web server machine.